# Docker mysql data not reflecting chages

Tags: mysql, docker, go, docker-compose

I am having some issues trying to run mysql with docker. I used this example

https://github.com/gpuenteallott/golang-mysql-docker-setup/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Which worked like a charm. SO I could then log into sequel pro host 127.0.0.1:3306. username, password =  gotest. Worked perfect. I then wanted to change the db name and login in details to I changed my docker-compose.yaml file to look like this

```
app_database:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/db/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
      MYSQL_DATABASE: big-website-2014
    volumes:
      - ../../../../_local_mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
```

I then run every thing but I cannot seem to log in. I can still log into with the old details and old database is still there. But not any of the new data.

I have tried stoping and removing all containers and images. Rebuild , every thing still no joy.

I have also tried using the docker ip address aswell.

Can some one please educate me on this matter please and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MySQL Data is in host directory `../../../../_local_mysql_data`. Remove that directory and then recreate your container with `docker-compose up -d`